# R Shiny checkboxInput automatically selected based on ondition

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have a datatable in Shiny where I want to insert a column with checkboxes. This works also so far without problems.
However, these checkboxes should be selected automatically when a certain condition is met.
I have used the iris dataset as an example and would like to set a mark in the respective checkbox if the value in `Sepal.Length` is greater than 5.
With my current approach, all checkboxes are selected and unfortunately not only those that meet the condition.
Can anyone help me with my problem?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyInput<-function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, ...))
  }
  inputs
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  dataTableOutput("table")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  table1 <- iris %>% 
    mutate(Check = shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(iris), 'check1', value = ifelse(Sepal.Length >= 5, TRUE, FALSE)))
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable({table1},
                  escape = F)
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

***Current output:***

[image]

***Desired output:***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function `shinyInput` and the way you use it are not correct for multiple reasons.

Rather create the `Check` column as follows:

```r
library(shiny)

shinyInput<-function(FUN, id, i, ...) {
  as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, ...))
}

values <- iris$Sepal.Length >= 5
Check <- vapply(1:nrow(iris), function(i) {
  shinyInput(checkboxInput, "checkb", i, value = values[i])
}, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! That is somewhat what I am looking for.
However, I would rather use a solution that is more oriented towards the `tidyverse` package and not `vapply`. Would you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: @TobKel - you could use `purrr::map_chr` instead of `vapply` and then remove the `FUN.VALUE` arg.